# Overlay Subsections in TOC with Beamer

Tags: beamer

In the beginning of my presentation, I would like to show the following. On the first slide, I would like to show a table of contents with sections only. That is, the subsections should be invisible, but they should be THERE. Then, on the following slides, the subsections shall sucessively be blended in.

Using the option `pausesubsections` for `\tableofcontents` has the disadvantage that only the first section is shown on the first slide. Using the option `hidesubsections` erases the subsections completely, so that it is impossible to blend them in one after another.

I tried setting up a fake table of contents with `enumerate` and `itemize` and using `\pause`, but the spacing is different from a 'real' table of contents. Below provided a MWE.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Outline}
    \tableofcontents[pausesubsections]
\end{frame}

\section{One}

\subsection{OneOne}
\begin{frame}
    There is nothing here.
\end{frame}

\subsection{OneTwo}
\begin{frame}
    There is nothing here.
\end{frame}


\section{Two}

\subsection{TwoOne}
\begin{frame}
    There is nothing here.
\end{frame}

\subsection{TwoTwo}
\begin{frame}
    There is nothing here.
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Maybe some inspiration: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/114689/beamer-toc-how-may-i-show-subsections-of-one-section-with-pausesections-option Does not answer your question, but maybe could be modified.

Answer (score 1):

Hiding the subsection, while preserving their space, can easily be done by colouring them in the background colour.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

{
\setbeamercolor{subsection in toc}{fg=bg}
\begin{frame}{Outline}
    \tableofcontents
\end{frame}
}

\begin{frame}{Outline}
    \tableofcontents[pausesubsections]
\end{frame}

\section{One}

\subsection{OneOne}
\begin{frame}
    There is nothing here.
\end{frame}

\subsection{OneTwo}
\begin{frame}
    There is nothing here.
\end{frame}


\section{Two}

\subsection{TwoOne}
\begin{frame}
    There is nothing here.
\end{frame}

\subsection{TwoTwo}
\begin{frame}
    There is nothing here.
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want to code something like this.  This works with beamer own commands.

On the first slide you get an outline with only the section titles.  Entering the sections a new outline will be presented, with the title of the subsections inserted and highlighted.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\mode<presentation>{%
  %% At the begin of a section, insert a short outline
  \AtBeginSection[]{%
    \begin{frame}<beamer>%
      \frametitle{Outline}
      \tableofcontents[currentsection,subsectionstyle=show/shaded/hide]%
    \end{frame}%
  }%
  %% 
  %% Same for Subsections
  \AtBeginSubsection[]{%
    \begin{frame}<beamer>%
      \frametitle{Outline}
      \tableofcontents[currentsection,subsectionstyle=show/shaded/hide]%
    \end{frame}}%
}
\begin{document}


\begin{frame}{Outline}
    \tableofcontents[currentsection,sectionstyle=show,hideothersubsections]
\end{frame}

\section{One}

\subsection{OneOne}
\begin{frame}
    There is nothing here.
\end{frame}

\subsection{OneTwo}
\begin{frame}
    There is nothing here.
\end{frame}


\section{Two}

\subsection{TwoOne}
\begin{frame}
    There is nothing here.
\end{frame}

\subsection{TwoTwo}
\begin{frame}
    There is nothing here.
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```